# MYSQL Select no matter the order

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select rows from a table depending on if the needs are met for the 'placement' column.

```
SELECT * FROM StuffType WHERE placement IN('L','V','X','XL','VL','LV');
```

See how I need to repeat LV as VL? Is there a way mysql can identify the row based on the content without the proper order?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess he doesn't want to have to put both 'VL' and 'LV' in the query?

Comment: I'm basically trying to select rows in a database where column 'placement' is equal to LV OR VL, but in a simpler way as there are many combinations

Comment: Would you want to fetch records matching `LX` too?

Comment: weird example.. no LX or LVX? If that were the case I would suggest substring search, but your example, I have no idea what you want... Your query looks just perfect to me...

Comment: do you have all combinations stored in another table or something?

Comment: How is MySQL supposed to know that the roman numeral `VL` is equal to `LV`?  What should it do if you specify `IX` for example -- should it also match `XI`, even though they are not equal?

Comment: it's not roman numerals, it's letters like A,B,C...

I have a wide array of options lets say I want to find rows with AB. I want to get all rows that are AB and BA in the field

Comment: @cdhowie: VL (45) != LV (55).

Comment: why don't you "normalize" it, so BA is stored as AB?

Comment: @eggyal Indeed, I derped on that.

Comment: What Karoly said. It's hard to write queries when your data lacks consistency.

Comment: Perhaps this is a good use case for MySQL's [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) datatype, which is implemented as a bitmask?

Comment: Can we go back a step or two? I'd say it's unlikely you're storing your information in the best way in the first place, which is why there's a problem. Can you explain a bit more about the (real) problem, and what your data represents, rather than use this slightly abstract example?

Comment: why use roman "numeral" STRINGS when you should be using a normal **INT** field, then convert to roman numerals when it comes time to display results?

Comment: @MarcB: "[*it's not roman numerals, it's letters like A,B,C*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287093/mysql-select-no-matter-the-order#comment23312445_16287093)"

Comment: @eggyal: yeah, I see that comment now.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to match all records containing any combination of those three letters, you can use [regular expression pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

```sql
WHERE placement RLIKE '^[LVX]+$'
```

Comment: there are not any combination, I think he wants only a few

Comment: Does that also include the pattern of just L, V, X, XV, LV, etc?

Comment: @ZachTester: Yes, this would be one or more of `LVX` in any order.

Comment: you store *username* in the actions table? you really should go back to the 1st class and learn to properly design your schemas...